# How to reliably check if Oracle is running on a remote host?

Tags: linux, oracle

We could just check if the remote port (usually 1521) is open but unfortunately Oracle opens this port during bootup process, so we cannot rely on it.
Any other ideas? Thanks!
(some background info: I am checking a remote oracle host from bash script)

update: seems like it is only possible with oracle client software

Comment: Have you considered a tnsping?

Comment: tnsping tests the listener and the connection.   One issue: if your DBA is doing something with the DB that prevents logging in, tnsping still returns okay.

Comment: yeah, some ppl on oracle irc channels told me that my only tool for this is the oracle client side stuff, thanks

Comment: maybe you should post this question to https://serverfault.com/

Comment: You could sql*plus to the server and run something simple like `select * from dual`, but of course that requires a user+password for the check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, because we agreed not to include client side stuff from Oracle to the context where we are doing this check, I implemented a minimal Java application that returns 0 if the Oracle DB is up and running and returns 1 otherwise.
This app can be repeatedly called from a script until it returns 0.
Under the hood, we are connecting to the Oracle DB with the JDBC driver and check V_$INSTANCE / STATUS table.

Answer (score 0):

ssh oracle@host "ps -ef|grep -i _smon_|grep -v grep|cut -d '_' -f3"

$ ps -ef|grep _smon_|grep -v grep|cut -d '_' -f3
prod
test

Comment: Please, [edit] and try for [answer], describe the effect of what you propose and explain why it helps to solve the problem. Find help with formatting your post here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting . Consider taking the [tour].